# Where does Firefox keep browsing history data?

Tags: storage, files, firefox-for-android, history

[This linked question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64257/how-do-i-retrieve-timestamps-from-my-firefox-download-history) describes how to find the *time* a file was *downloaded* in Android for Mobile.

How does one do the same for *browsing* history?  What file is that information stored in?

Comment: Look into /data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/PROFILE/

Comment: @Firelord I did but haven't found anything that has the history in it...is there a particular **file** I should be trying to get that information from?